# Using nhibernate <loader> element with HQL queries

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hql

I'm attempting to use an HQL query in a `<loader>` element to load an entity based on other entities.

My class is as follows

```
public class ParentOnly
{
    public ParentOnly(){}
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string ParentObjectName { get; set; }
}
```

and the mapping looks like this

```
<class name="ParentOnly">
  <id name="Id">
    <generator class="identity" />
  </id>
  <property name="ParentObjectName" />
  <loader query-ref="parentonly"/>
</class>

<query name="parentonly" >
  select new ParentOnly() 
  from SimpleParentObject as spo
  where spo.Id = :id
</query>
```

The class that I am attemping to map on top of is SimpleParentObject, which has its own mapping and can be loaded and saved without problems.

When I call session.Get`<ParentOnly>`(id) the sql runs correctly against the SimpleParentObject table, and a ParentOnly object is instantiated (as I can step through the constructer), but only a null comes back, rather than the instantiated ParentOnly object.

I can do this succesfully using a  instead of the HQL, but am trying to build this in a database independent fashion.

Any thoughts on how to get the `<loader>` and `<query>` elements to return a populated ParentOnly object...?

Thanks

Matt

Comment: The HQL query is generated by a tool btw, for anyone wondering why one would want to use this.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the nHibernate documentation, changing the select statement should fix this problem.

```
<query name="parentonly" >
  select ParentObjectNameAS {spo.Name}, Id AS {spo.Id}
  from SimpleParentObject as spo
  where spo.Id = :id
</query>
```

source: http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/